# Incorrect Syntax in Stored procedure - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, stored-procedures, django-rest-framework, pyodbc

I'm just trying to implement the stored procedure from the MSSQL in the API post method. Basically, the email and password stored in the Database if the user exist I want to redirect to the next page.

I'm getting issue with the stored procedure implementation How could I able to pass the input to the stored procedure.

I don't want to pass the input in hardcoded way the input which I'm getting from the UI part for the email and password in the UI (Angular) as it suppose to take the email and password in the POST method and redirect to next page.

```
"driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", SQL version -15.0
```

error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Api\app\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import (
  File "C:\UsersApi\app\views.py", line 38, in <module>
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_CheckOneQUserStatus]  @param1=%s @param2=%s', ('VID', 'Password'))
  File "C:\Users\\Api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\\Api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", 
line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Api\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Api\venv\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 536, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@param2'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST']) 
def CheckUserStatusView(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
            serializer = CheckUserStatusSerializers(users, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
  
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_CheckUserStatus] @VID=%s, @Password=%s', ('demouser@demo.com', 'NewUser@1'))
            result_set = cursor.fetchone()
            print(result_set)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Stored Procedure:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO     
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckUserStatus]          
      @VID varchar(100),          
      @Password varchar(200)           
           
AS          
BEGIN          
      SET NOCOUNT ON;     
       
select  A.UserId,A.Fullname,A.SubFunctionName ,UserRole       
from tblusers A         
where A.EmailId=@VID and A.Password=@Password  and A.IsActive=1    

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_CheckUserStatus] @param1=%s @param2=%s', ('VID', 'Password'))
```

to

```
cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_CheckUserStatus] %s, %s', (VID, Password))
```

Comment: this doesn't works. I have edited my code now there shouldn't been any parameter... VID and Password which comes from the user's input that has to be validate with the DB

Comment: I have edited the code now I'm getting incorrect syntax do u have any idea about it

Comment: there's no @param2 named variable in you procedure, you can try to replace it with actual variable names

Comment: I have edited I have replaced param with actual values still  same error exist in the second value          ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@Password'.

Comment: I have fixed the syntax issue when I hard code it only im getting the output rather than getting the input from UI